# How can I find the root implementation of an interface in Go?

Tags: go

I have an interface `RootInterface` embedded in a struct `OneConcrete`. This concrete implementation of the interface is then embedded into another struct `TwoConcrete` as `RootInterface` again.

How do I determine that the actual implementation of `RootInterface` is `OneConcrete`? The following code hopefully shows what I am trying to achieve:

http://play.golang.org/p/YrwDRwQzDc

```
package main

import "fmt"

type RootInterface interface {
    GetInt() int
}

type OneConcrete struct {
}

func (oc OneConcrete) GetInt() int {
    return 1
}

type TwoConcrete struct {
    RootInterface
}

func main() {
    one := OneConcrete{}
    fmt.Println("One", one.GetInt())

    two := RootInterface(TwoConcrete{RootInterface: one})

    _, ok := two.(TwoConcrete)
    fmt.Println(ok) // prints true

    // How can I get the equivalent of ok == true,
    // i.e. find out that OneConcrete is the acutal
    // RootInterface implementation?
    _, ok = two.(OneConcrete)
    fmt.Println(ok) // prints false
}
```

Note that I would like an answer to the general case where `RootInterface` could be embedded arbitrarily deeply within a struct hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OneConcrete` does not embeds interface. It implements that interface. Embedding a type mean that struct will get one additional field with same name as given type and all methods of that type will become methods of struct. So, to get `OneConcrete` you should do `two.(TwoConcrete).RootInterface.(OneConcrete)`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Say I had a struct called `FiveConcrete` and I wanted to see if there was a `TwoConcrete` implementation ie.` five.(FourConcrete).RootInterface.(ThreeConcrete).RootInterface.(TwoConcrete)...`. Is there a generic way to follow an arbitrary length chain until I find `TwoConcrete` or reach the root?

Comment: It is not possible to traverse arbitrary struct embedding tree since `reflect` package cannot distinguish struct own methods from 'inherited'. And, if your interface have more than one method, `root implementation` cannot be defined if some type in hierarchy overloads one of interface methods.